# AWS S3 RequestTimeTooSkewed from browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is this known issue in S3 that if the system for whatever reason has its clock not synched, the upload fails with `RequestTimeTooSkewed` error.

There are many solutions to when this is triggered by a server (basically fixing the server clock) but what can I do when this is triggered by the browser of my app users?

Even setting `correctClockSkew` to `true` doesn't fix it.

```
AWS.config.update({
  correctClockSkew: true,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution for JavaScript in the browser to correct client-side clock skew. Your client sends a HEAD request to an S3 bucket (so permissions would be required, or you use a public bucket, and you'd need CORS on the bucket to expose the data header):

```
correctClockSkew = (Bucket) => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    // Head the bucket to get a Date response. The 'date' header
    // will need to be exposed in S3 CORS configuration.
    s3.headBucket({ Bucket }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('headBucket error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('headBucket data:', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('headBucket headers:', JSON.stringify(this.httpResponse.headers));

            if (this.httpResponse.headers.date) {
                const date = Date.parse(this.httpResponse.headers.date);
                console.log('headers date:', date);
                AWS.config.systemClockOffset = new Date() - date;
                console.log('clock offset:', AWS.config.systemClockOffset);
                // Can now safely generate presigned urls
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This is borrowed from the [aws-js-s3-explorer](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-js-s3-explorer/blob/v2-alpha/explorer.js) project.

Another option is to wait for the retry event (borrowed from [this comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/399#issuecomment-233057244)):

```
AWS.events.on('retry', function (response: any) {
  if (response.error.name === 'RequestTimeTooSkewed') {
    var serverTime = Date.parse(response.httpResponse.headers['date']);
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    AWS.config.systemClockOffset = Math.abs(timeNow - serverTime);
    response.error.retryable = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Setting AWS.config.systemClockOffset seems to fix S3 but breaks MediaConverter, see updated post above

Comment: I noticed that you added that just after I posted. I don't see an easy way to get around  the global AWS.config settings unless you somehow manipulate the clock skew before each S3 call and then reset it it afterwards. Any chance you can simply request that the client time-sync their machine?

Comment: No, also because some users seem to have the time set correctly.

Comment: Stepping back, I don't see why 'correcting' the SDK's clock would break something.

Comment: In fact I wonder if MediaConverter fails too in those cases (regardless of the systemClockOffset change) and need its own fix too. It seems so.

Comment: mmm CORS doesn't seem to be an issue in the systems without the RequestTimeTooSkewed error : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3431

Comment: I accepted your answer since I think I'm facing a different problem with MediaConverter.